# Dropdown pulling from database influencing next drop down menu

Tags: php, sql

Hello I have a drop down menu pulling from a database. Based off of this selection I want to display a list of options under that category. Here is a picture of the database that I wish to pull from each one is assigned an ID according to each selection. https://i.stack.imgur.com/er69z.jpg
Here is what I have

```
`
<?php
require ("dbconnect.php");
$db = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);
?>

<div class="label">Select Store:</div>

<select name="stores">
<option value = "">---Select---</option>
<?php
$queryusers = "SELECT * FROM `storeconst` ORDER BY `Store` ASC";
$db = mysqli_query($db, $queryusers);
while ( $d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($db)) {
echo "<option value='{".$d['Store']."}'>".$d['Store']."</option>";
}
?>
  </select>  
<?php
require ("dbconnect.php");
echo ("<br>");

$db = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);
?>

<div class="label">Incident Type:</div>

<select name="names">
<option value = "">---Select---</option>
<?php
$queryusers = " SELECT * FROM `infractiontype` ORDER BY `infractiontype`.`IncidentType` ASC";
$db = mysqli_query($db, $queryusers);
while ( $d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($db)) {
echo "<option value='{".$d['infractiontype']."}'>".$d['IncidentType']."</option>";
}
?>
  </select> 
<?php
require ("dbconnect.php");
echo ("<br>");

$db = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);
?>

<div class="label">Incident Severity:</div>

<select name="names">
<option value = "">---Select---</option>
<?php
$queryusers = " SELECT * FROM `severitytype` ORDER BY `SeverityType`.`ID` ASC";
$db = mysqli_query($db, $queryusers);
while ( $d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($db)) {
echo "<option value='{".$d['severitytype']."}'>".$d['SeverityType']."</option>";
}
?>
  </select>
```

dbconnect.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "admin";
$password = "pass";
$db = "log";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
?>
```

What would I need to do in order for my next dropdown to be based off of Incident Type and Incident Severity?

Cheers

Comment: you need to fire off an ajax request after selecting the 2nd option, which calls a php script to query for the new options to be displayed on the menu, and then the callback for that request populates the menu into the DOM

Comment: I know nothing about ajax can you link me to an article?

Comment: umm, hmm, let's see. w3schools is usually a terrible source of information, but this article actually looks decent: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp. Additionally, if there aren't a ton of options, @Misunderstood's solution of just showing and hiding elements without ajax would also work

Comment: line 7 $db undefined!  please post code that you have tested

Comment: yeah, but that's after line 7.

Comment: Sorry had the ` for stackoverflow in the wrong spot. The code is updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the number of options.

A few options: Create HTML for all the possible SELECT with a style of display:none

Based on the selection use JavaScript to change the .style.display ='block' (or inline-block)

If a lot of options:  Pass the selected option via AJAX where the returned value is the options HTML and use innerHTML to add the options.

If you pic on imgur is inclusive and you do not know AJAX the quicker easier route is to use the CSS none/block method. 
 
**HTML**

```
<select id="sel" onchange="getNext();">
   <option value="1">Option1</option>
   <option value="2">Option2</option>
   <option value="3">Option3</option>
   <option value="4">Option4</option>
</select>

<select id="sel1">
   <option>Option11</option>
   <option>Option12</option>
   <option>Option13</option>
   <option>Option14</option>
</select>
<select id="sel2">
   <option>Option21</option>
   <option>Option22</option>
   <option>Option23</option>
   <option>Option24</option>
</select>
<select id="sel3">
   <option>Option31</option>
   <option>Option32</option>
   <option>Option33</option>
   <option>Option34</option>
</select>
```

**CSS**

```
#sel1,#sel2,#sel3{display:none;}
```

**JS**

```
function getNext(){
  var sel = document.getElementById('sel');
  var next = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
  document.getElementById('sel' + next).style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: All of this information is going to be stored in a table in the database once selected and sent. http://imgur.com/VOi9ydB if you haven't seen this, this lists all of my options with each ID.

Comment: If the options are going to be dynamic then create the HTML in PHP.  If not, hard code the HTML.

Comment: You can create a blank dummy SELECT then set its style to 'none' when you change the other to 'block' or inline-block'